# prove lim as x approaches to 1, f(x)= + infinite,

Tags: limits

I have a hard time understanding the example of computing the limit, 
here is the full question ：

[image]

Why do we need to solve neighborhood $\varepsilon$ of $x$?

How did it goes to :
[image]

I'm so confused..
I thought I just need to use the definition of limit to find $M$ by the inequality $f(x) > M$
to find $\delta$ such that $|x - x_0| < \delta$?

Comment: In the definition it says "there is $\epsilon$ so that $|x - x_0| < \delta$", but it should be $\epsilon$ instead of $\delta$. In the proof you may call it $\epsilon$ or $\delta$, it doesn't really matter, it's just a name

Comment: I still don't understand how did he find the value of $M$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a typo (and a severe one) in the definition, but I think there is confusion on your part as well, which I'll try to remedy.

To show $\lim_{x\to x_0}f(x)=+\infty$ you must show that given *any* $M>0$ there exists $\epsilon>0$ such that if $|x-x_0|<\epsilon$ then $f(x)>M$. (In the definition from your book, the second $\epsilon$ is replaced by a $\delta$. This is a typo.)

So there is no "finding $M$" to be done. $M$ isn't something you get to choose; it's just given to you. You need to find $\epsilon$ that makes the above proposition hold. This is why the author is going through those inequalities: he's trying to find what values of $\epsilon$ will make $f(x)>M$ in a $\epsilon$-neighborhood of $x_0=1$.

Comment: I undertand the concept of finding $\epsilon$, but I don't know how that inequality come from.  $|x|/|1-x|  >= 1/2/\epsilon$, how?

Comment: Since $x\in B(1,\epsilon)$ by definition $|1-x|<\epsilon$. So $1/|1-x|>1/\epsilon$. Also, $|x|\geq 1/2$ because $x\in(1-\epsilon,1+\epsilon)\subset(1/2, 3/2)$ (using $\epsilon < 1/2$). Put these together and you get the inequality.